Cannot install Python packages because of urllib3
I am trying to run a Python script:
python main.py

obtaining this output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import stateful
  File "/path/to/s.py", line 599, in <module>
    import policy as offloading_policy
  File "/path/to/p.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pacsltk import perfmodel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pacsltk'

Process finished with exit code 1

... but not only pacsltk is already installed: when I try to install it anyways (pip install pacsltk), I obtain:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pacsltk
  Downloading pacsltk-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting boto3>=1.11.5 (from pacsltk)
  Downloading boto3-1.35.54-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pacsltk) (1.24.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.4.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pacsltk) (1.10.1)
Collecting botocore<1.36.0,>=1.35.54 (from boto3>=1.11.5->pacsltk)
  Downloading botocore-1.35.54-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3>=1.11.5->pacsltk) (1.0.1)
Collecting s3transfer<0.11.0,>=0.10.0 (from boto3>=1.11.5->pacsltk)
  Downloading s3transfer-0.10.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from botocore<1.36.0,>=1.35.54->boto3>=1.11.5->pacsltk) (2.8.2)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 (from botocore<1.36.0,>=1.35.54->boto3>=1.11.5->pacsltk)
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (50 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.36.0,>=1.35.54->boto3>=1.11.5->pacsltk) (1.14.0)
WARNING: No metadata found in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Downloading pacsltk-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Downloading boto3-1.35.54-py3-none-any.whl (139 kB)
Downloading botocore-1.35.54-py3-none-any.whl (12.7 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.7/12.7 MB 901.6 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading s3transfer-0.10.3-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Downloading urllib3-1.26.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (144 kB)
WARNING: Error parsing dependencies of attrs: [Errno 2] File o directory non esistente: '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attrs-23.1.0.dist-info/METADATA'
WARNING: Error parsing dependencies of urllib3: [Errno 2] File o directory non esistente: '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3-2.0.4.dist-info/METADATA'
Installing collected packages: urllib3, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, pacsltk
  Attempting uninstall: urllib3
    WARNING: No metadata found in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    Found existing installation: urllib3 2.0.4
error: uninstall-no-record-file

× Cannot uninstall urllib3 2.0.4
╰─> The package's contents are unknown: no RECORD file was found for urllib3.

hint: You might be able to recover from this via: pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps urllib3==2.0.4

Furthermore, when I try to run the suggested command pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps urllib3==2.0.4, I am only able to obtain just the same error:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting urllib3
  Downloading urllib3-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
WARNING: No metadata found in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Downloading urllib3-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3
  Attempting uninstall: urllib3
    WARNING: No metadata found in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    Found existing installation: urllib3 2.0.4
error: uninstall-no-record-file

× Cannot uninstall urllib3 2.0.4
╰─> The package's contents are unknown: no RECORD file was found for urllib3.

hint: You might be able to recover from this via: pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps urllib3==2.0.4

Similar error when trying to pip uninstall urllib3.
Also, sudo apt-get autoremove/purge applied to python-urllib3 just says that the package is not installed.
The same error with urllib3 seems to be applied with whatever python package I want to install. I have looked to several other questions with this error without getting to solve this problem. What can I do?

EDIT
Tried @x1337Loser's answer: now everything runs smoothly, but I had the following output after the pip command:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
(... some `Requirement already satisfied` row...)
WARNING: Error parsing dependencies of attrs: [Errno 2] File o directory non esistente: '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attrs-23.1.0.dist-info/METADATA'`

I am glad my program is now running, but what is that warning?

Try this py -3.8 -m pip install urllib3

Thanks, I tried but it suggested me to run sudo apt install pythonpy because package was not installed. Another solution worked, so I did not continue with the installation. Thank you anyways :)

Based on the error messages, some previously installed packages must have installed urllib3 v2.0.4 as a requirement, and its possible there were installed via a method other than pip if there is no uninstall record, or the necessary logs were removed at some point.  Looking at the release history They have been actively releasing updates on both the v1 and v2 branches this year.

Thank you, yes, maybe I did some kind of damage/mis-uninstallation of some kind.

A few days ago I faced a similar problem with python-requests and these steps worked for me [Don't use sudo while installing, because this seems to work when you move to sudo but installing a package with sudo is harmful who knows what you're installing is a malware in a package form]:
Remove the package manually from the site-packages directory:
cd ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/

rm -rf urllib3*

now install your package:
pip install pacsltk --upgrade

let me know if this solves your problem

Thank you for your answered: it now works, but with a stange warning. I posted my reply to you into the edited post.

same error with attrs modules, you can follow the same steps with the attrs, I am glad this worked for you, actually this packaging error is now common in a lot of Debian distros, so if you face a similar error like METADATA file is not found or No such file or folder found then you can follow above steps, again if you use sudo then this issue seems fixed but this is not a professional and also a harmful step for Linux as sudo will give an attacker complete access on your machine

Did it, and now everything runs smoothly and without any error/warning. Thank you!

It seems like python and pip packages are corrupted. Try the following :

Uninstall any python or pip package installed on your system
Reinstall the python and pip and all the package and modules as well.

Let me know if it works.
I installed 'scratch' but i encountered exactly same error.Then I did this and it ran smoothly.

Hi, thank you for the answer. Could you provide some details on how to do it? I ask it since, as written in the post, the sudo apt-get autoremove/purge approach seems to be ineffective.
